# How to Force Powershell console Process to exit and keep going from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

Running Powershell script from C# in a Process. The script runs fine, but the console just hangs there waiting.

Here's my code:

```
 public static int RunPowershellScript(string ps)
    {
        int errorLevel;
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
        Process process;
        var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe", "-File " + ps);
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();

        errorLevel = process.ExitCode;
        process.Close();

        return errorLevel;
    }
```

What do I need to do to tell this method to just get out after the script is done?

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't know C#, but as far as the script goes, you could end it with `Exit` or `Break` and that should close the console when the script is done.

Comment: what happens when you run your powershell script in powershell?

Comment: what happens when you set `processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;`?

Comment: two consoles come up, one for main and one for powershell run. still just sits and waits when script finishes.

Comment: When I try your code with a very simple script that just prints the current date, it works fine. The console does not hang. Some suggestions: (1) try winnowing your script down to the bare mimimum; you may discover some command in there that is holding the window open. (2) Try specifying the `-NonInteractive` parameter to PowerShell.exe. (3) Instead of launching PowerShell in a separate process, consider using the [`PowerShell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell(v=vs.85).aspx) class in the `System.Management.Automation` assembly to run the script.

Comment: Tried -Noninteractive, didn't work, also tried putting an Exit at the end of the script and still the same behaviour.

Comment: Did you try winnowing down the script per Brian's suggestion? If the script is long, I recommend a binary search strategy. Cut the script by half, see it it fails. If  it does cut that part by half. if it doesn't fail add back in half of what you originally cut out.